# Application in VB6 to send and receive messages through MQ to another system

Tags: vb6, ibm-mq

I have to develop an application in VB6 to read records from Oracle tables format it as per the defined message type and send it over to another application via Websphere MQ,i am a beginner in VB .Please suggest how should i proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are VB6 samples shipped with MQ and you can find them under `tool/VB/SampVB6` folder of your MQ installation. `amsputb` and `amqsgetb` samples will be useful to you.

Are you bound by any limitation for developing your application using VB6? My recommendation would be to use the .NET Framework (VB .NET or C#) for your development. MQ recommends the usage of MQ .NET assemblies as the .NET assemblies are more `up to date` and lot of features implemented compared to VB interface.

**EDIT**
Answering your questions:
a) Yes, multiple applications can put/get to/from the same queue.
b) Each program can set a unique CorrelationId when a sending a message. The intermediate program can use the CorrelationId to identify the program that is sending message. Intermediate program must have some knowledge of which CorrelationId maps to which program.

Is there reason for intermediate program needs to identify the sender application?

Comment: If you want to get picky, they'd rather see you use Java.  This is as viable an answer as a .Net language if you're going to rule out VB6.

Comment: There is currently an interface in VB6 which acts as an intermediate program to read messages from a table populated by an application,this intermediate program then post messages in MQ and updates the table accordingly,my organisations want me to extend this intermediate prog to be used by other applications as well.Now the questions is:a)Can the same Q be used for multiple applications.b)If yes then how can the intermediate prog distinguish between messages generated by different program.c)one possible way is to use separate instance of the intermediate prog,suggestions are welcome.

Comment: yes because of high volume of transactions intermediate prog must update the tables of each program separately